# Can run program in code editor but not in Python IDE

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, uuid

It works perfectly fine when I run it on Visual Studio Code, but doesn't open on Python Shell. BTW, I have Python 3.1 and Python 3.9.

```
import uuid
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

run_id = uuid.uuid1()

print(f'Processing run_id: {run_id}')

image = Image.new('RGB', (2000, 2000))
width, height = image.size

rectangle_width = 100
rectangle_height = 100

number_of_squares = random.randint(90, 350)

draw_image = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for i in range(number_of_squares):
    rectangle_x = random.randint(0, width)
    rectangle_y = random.randint(0, height)

    rectangle_shape = [
        (rectangle_x, rectangle_y),
        (rectangle_x + rectangle_width, rectangle_y + rectangle_height)]
    draw_image.rectangle(
        rectangle_shape,
        fill=(
            random.randint(0, 255),
            random.randint(0, 255),
            random.randint(0, 255)
        )
    )

image.save(f'output.png')
image.show(f'output.png')
```

I created a desktop shortcut of the ".py" program I made and open the file on "Python" or "Python 3.9". Both ways don't work. I do this on every program I code. This one can't be opened.

It works perfectly fine when I run it on Visual Studio Code, but doesn't open on Python Shell. I wonder why? What should I do or add to the code?

Comment: Run the script from the command line and see what errors are printed.

Comment: I open command prompt and type "python3 -m genart" which "genart.py" is the name of my .py file. And it opened! but how to run it using python?

Comment: You are running it with python. To run it from within the python *shell*, just `import` it.

Comment: Oh, okay, I did what you said and it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'". Now I know what's the problem, I will work out on this next. Thank you for helping!

Comment: That's good news — glad to hear you're getting somewhere.